# How to Initialize the same Class in its same constructor in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a class as like below,

```
public class ClassA
{
  public ClassA()
{
     ClassAList = new List<SomeOtherClassA>();
     ClassBList = new List<SomeOtherClassB>();
     ClassCList = new List<SomeOtherClassC>();
     errorRecords  = new ClassA();
}
public List<SomeOtherClassA>ClassAList {get;set;}
public List<SomeOtherClassB>ClassBList {get;set;}
public List<SomeOtherClassC>ClassCList {get;set;}

public ClassA errorRecords {get;set;}

}
```

when errorRecords is initialized it is creating the continuous looping.
How to initialize errorRecords without the endless loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically you have to solve this elsehow. If your class `A` always needs an instance of another class `A`, then it will end in some recursive infinite loop. You could for example have your `errorRecords` field set from outside in a method.

Comment: If errorRecords should not have its errorRecords set, it might not be of type ClassA. Change its type.

Comment: The technical problems almost certainly hide a bad architectural decision. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need a errorRecords to be initialized without accessing it from a helper method or something else - you could convert the property to a full property with a private backing field.

When you first access the property you could initialize the private backing field with a new `ClassA`.

For example:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
  public ClassA()
  {
      ClassAList = new List<SomeOtherClassA>();
      ClassBList = new List<SomeOtherClassB>();
      ClassCList = new List<SomeOtherClassC>();
  }
  public List<SomeOtherClassA>ClassAList {get;set;}
  public List<SomeOtherClassB>ClassBList {get;set;}
  public List<SomeOtherClassC>ClassCList {get;set;}

  public ClassA errorRecords 
  {
      get
      {
          _errorRecords ??= new();
          return _errorRecords;
      }
      set
      {
          _errorRecords = value;
      }
  }
  private ClassA _errorRecords;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DekuDesu, But when I do like that, I can see the errorRecords is listed many times in IntelliSense and also I can access it like ClassAInstance.errorRecords.errorRecords.errorRecords.ClassAList. How to prevent that ?

Comment: When ClassA has an ErrorRecords property of that same ClassA, that will also have that ErrorRecords property, which will also ... . Maybe it should be some ErrorClassA?

Comment: @user3616471, Its logical that any ClassA that has a errorRecords property should also have them since all the classes will be the same. The work around provided helps you to avoid a stack overflow on initialization. I would recommend a different pattern if this is not desirable. Honestly I would recommend leaving the property null and giving it a value later(not in the constructor).